# Why would a website use artificially long response times?

Tags: http, web, get

I've noticed, on some websites, that there are recurrent http get requests taking equally long times to download a very small amount of data (around 5 lines of text).

Like a heartbeat, these requests are also chained in such a way that there is *always* something going on in the background.

[image: Consistently long content download times]

It is present in multiple well known websites. For example, see Gmail and facebook are both using this technique for their hearthbeats

[image]

**How can one reproduce this behaviour?**

**And why would someone use this technique on his website?**

Edit:

My hypothesis is that they can now control the refresh times of *all* clients by adjusting a single value in the server application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is an implementation of [*long polling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling). It's arguably a hack to simulate push updates to the browser, enabling real time updates of the page as soon as something of importance happens on the server.

Comment: Thanks! It seems so obvious now. A wise use of web technologies. Quickly found myself reading this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/how-to-implement-basic-long-polling